# Replacing all ",NULL," occurence in Ruby string

Tags: ruby, csv

Trying to pre-process a CSV file that may contain `"NULL"` strings that represent `null` values so that all the "NULL" strings are removed

I tried the following but it doesn't exactly work as intended...

```
test_str = "...,NULL,NULL,value,NULL,..."
test_str.gsub! ",NULL," ",," # >> outputs "...,,NULL,value,,..."
```

As you can see one NULL wasn't removed.

If my pattern is just `"NULL"` then it may remove actual real values. Same if I use `",NULL"` or `"NULL,"`.

How can I achieve my desired output of `"...,,,value,..."` ?

Or if there is a better way of proceeding I'm open to suggestions!

Thanks!

Comment: Do you need to do this with Ruby?

Comment: @erip: Yes this is part of one of my Ruby on Rails background job

Comment: I would recommend `test_str.gsub! "NULL" ""` if there won't be any false positives.

Comment: @erip: It's likely there will be false positive. I can't restrict a user for naming a value `MYVALUE_NULL`, which is a value, not a `NULL`

Comment: There are several cases: first value is NULL, some middle value is NULL, last value is NULL. These all have different `gsub` rules.

Comment: `NULL` is probably a good thing to restrict a user from using as a name in any case.

Comment: @erip. Yup I agree. I think if I'm dealing with the middle case right now. Nonethles it's not working. I can't restrict a user from having NULL values. It's because some SQL Software (MS SqlServ Studio for example) export null values as "NULL" (thanks MS)

Comment: Does it need to be preprocessed like this? Why can't you just map values that are "NULL" after you parse it into nil?

Comment: @Piccolo: I thought it'd be the most "efficient way" (say if I have a large CSV). I should map key value of hashes to key, nulled_if_null(value) ?

Comment: Don't CSVs parse into arrays not hashes? I was thinking something along the lines of ``CSV.parse(str).map { |value| value == "NULL" ? nil : value }``

Comment: Wait CSVs return 2D arrays because they separate lines into different arrays. You'd have to combine the above code with ``#each`` to get all the data.

Comment: @Piccolo that solution works thanks! I hope it's computationally efficient

Comment: I posted it as an answer so this question can be marked as complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just remove the values after you parse the CSV file?

```
require 'csv'
data = []
CSV.parse(str).each do |line|
  data << line.map { |value| value == "NULL" ? nil : value }
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Not the nicest way of doing it, but it seems to work:

```
test_str = test_str.gsub(",NULL,", ",,").gsub(",NULL,", ",,")
```